# Ambiguous mapping error

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, mapping, ambiguous

I am working on a **Spring MVC project in IntelliJ**, hosted on **Tomcat 6.0.44**, using **JDK 1.8.0_60**. My whole team is running our application without any issues. On my machine, when I try to run the latest code from Git, the same code the rest of the team is running, I get this error:

> Context initialization failed Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'CartValidate' method.

There are 2 `CartValidate` methods (one POST, one GET), and a `view` method in the same controller that seem to be causing this issue.

If I change the request mappings for these 3 methods (I don't have to change the method names, just the request mappings), then it works fine.

I've searched the full codebase for the request mapping values, and they don't occur anywhere else, so I can't understand why there would be a problem with the original request mappings. The original request mappings are `cart/validate.json` and `cart/view.json`.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Here is the code for the 3 methods for which I need to change the request mapping to make the code run:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart/view.json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public Order view(@RequestParam(value = "orderId") Long orderId,
                   HttpServletRequest aRequest, HttpServletResponse aResponse) {

    Order order = orderService.orderGet(aRequest, aResponse, orderId);
    return order;
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart/validate.json", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public OrderWeb CartValidate(@RequestBody OrderWeb aModel,
                          HttpServletRequest aRequest, HttpServletResponse aResponse) {

    String orderId = aModel.getOrderId().toString();
    OrderWeb order = orderService.orderValidatePost(aModel, orderId,
            aRequest, aResponse);

    return order;
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart/validate.json", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public OrderWeb CartValidate(@RequestParam(value = "orderId", required = true) Long orderId,
                          HttpServletRequest aRequest, HttpServletResponse aResponse) {

    OrderWeb aModel = (OrderWeb) orderService.orderGet(aRequest, aResponse, orderId);
    OrderWeb order = orderService.orderValidatePost(aModel, orderId.toString(),
            aRequest, aResponse);
    return order;
}
```

Comment: it would be nice to see the code just an ambiguous question like this is hard to answer.

Comment: I've just added the code for the 3 methods in question.